# Difference between OrderByDescending (OrderBy) and AddOrder

Tags: linq, nhibernate, hibernate-criteria

this code

```
criteria
.AddOrder(new Order("AnnoInizialePfk", false))
.List<MyClass>()        
.ToDictionary(x => (short)x.AnnoInizialePfk, x => Convert.ToString(x.AnnoInizialePfk));
```

produce this sql

```
SELECT this_.ANNO_INIZIALE_PFK as y0_ FROM dbo.Table this_ ORDER BY y0_ desc
```

instead this code

```
criteria
.List<MyClass>()
.OrderByDescending(x => x.AnnoInizialePfk)
.ToDictionary(x => (short)x.AnnoInizialePfk, x => Convert.ToString(x.AnnoInizialePfk));
```

produce this sql

```
SELECT this_.ANNO_PFK as y0_ FROM dbo.Table this_
```

both resultset are order by descending, but how is it possible in the second code?

And which code is better to use?

Thanks

Sara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List()` call in the second statement makes it enumerate the Select straight away. i.e. The 'OrderBy' is done in memory, not at the DB. You should swap the OrderBy and List calls (although you don't really need the List as it is redundant because ToDictionary will do the same).

Comment: Oh, and unless you have a particular reason to use the `AddOrder()` syntax (serialization of queries?) I'd stick to the standard LINQ `OrderBy()` methods.

Comment: No, in this case is indifferent. I also prefear the second code because I can use the object name instead the column name.